# VBA object required excel.range error

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

Im trying to make a function for a vba lookup formula it goes like this.

```
 Private Function setVlookUp(Optional startingRow As Long, _
                   Optional endingRow As Long, _
                   Optional column As Long, _
                   Optional lookup_value_col As Long, _
                   Optional table_Array As String, _
                   Optional ByRef table_Array_FirstCell As Excel.Range, _
                   Optional table_Array_SecondCell As Excel.Constants, _
                   Optional col_num As Long, _
                   Optional range_lookup As Long, _
                   Optional isSetNumberFormat As Boolean = False, _
                   Optional NumberFormat As String)

    Dim rowCounter As Long
    With mWorksheet
        For rowCounter = startingRow To endingRow
                .Cells(rowCounter, column).Value = "=VLOOKUP(" & .Cells(rowCounter, lookup_value_col).Address(False, False) & ",'" & table_Array & "'!" & table_Array_FirstCell & ":" & table_Array_SecondCell & "," & col_num & "," & range_lookup & ")"
        Next rowCounter
    End With
```

and this is me calling the function

```
 Call setVlookUp(4, rowEnd, 4, 3, mArraySheetName(sheetCounter - 1, 0), .Cells(6, mArrayIntLocation(0, 0)).Address(False, False))
```

but there is an error that says "object required". And I cant find the problem.

Comment: Should you be using a Sub instead of a Function? You don't want to return any values right, just execute some commands..

Comment: @lllpratll tried using sub. I want to make this so my classmates can use this block of codes when they need.

Comment: you can still pass arguments to a sub, i don't see the problem..

Comment: @lllpratll there seems to be a problem with this code `.Cells(6, mArrayIntLocation(0, 0)).Address(False, False))`  with `table_Array_FirstCell` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string when the Function/Sub expects a range.

```
.Cells(6, mArrayIntLocation(0, 0)).Address(False, False)
```

This will return the address as a String (e.g. the string `"A6"`). To get the range, just remove the `.Address` and use

```
.Cells(6, mArrayIntLocation(0, 0))
```

When dealing with (this many) arguments, especially with optional arguments, I would always specify the argument in the function call to keep it readable, e.g.

```
Call setVlookUp(startingRow:=4, _
                endingRow:=rowEnd, _
                ...
                )
```